# Calculating hosting requirements for a new project?

Tags: mysql, bandwidth, vps, ram

When you are planning requirments on a new project with a new client, what methods can you use to calculate their hosting requirements?

I am meeting with a new client, and I am fine in terms of the capabilities of the server in terms of what technologies need to be compatible etc.

However, what methods can you use to calculate how much bandwidth, storage space and RAM they will need.

Are there any methods for getting a rough estimate? I won't make a profit on hosting, but I want my client to get what they need at the right price, and avoid problems down the road.

It's a new site, so we don't have an idea how much bandwidth the average page is consuming, the site is going to be feature rich, and will have functionality similar to popular Job Hunting websites, although that's not all that the site will be.

I've already estimated that a VPS is going to be needed, rather than shared hosting. I think any serious website needs VPS or better. And this should be getting a lot of traffic on a daily basis.

Plus it does lead to a lot more control over the environment, and avoids the need for control panels taking up resources.

I could host the dev version of the site on my own server and run some tests if there are tools available for measuring bandwith etc, then from that recommend a hosting package nearer the end of the project, when most of the features are in place.

In terms of RAM is it a good starting point to check the requirements of running an instance of the databse (mySQL) and everything else then tally those up?

Answer (score -1):

All the things requested by you are practically available and for new website, where the amount to data is not sure, the number of click are not sure and also number of pages are not sure then it makes the more complex to calculate the data. With dynamic website the calculations becomes more complex. For calculating these things first I recommend you to complete the development process with the completion of development process of dynamic website you will know what is the rough page consumption of bandwidth. Then you have to multiply that rough with your traffic i.e. how much times that page would be clicked or supposed to be clicked. That the time of loading note down the RAM usage of the page and on try to divide the RAM usage in fragments as loading of page and you can calculate the RAM requirement on each event. The things you are talking is more complex on the paper work but in piratically easy to do.